# magento 1.9 redirect to cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, redirect-url

i am using magento 1.9 i have some products on home page and on category pages there is a button called **"Buy Now"** when user click on the button its make redirect to **"Add cart"** page, i need it to **redirect to Product page**.
already try:
**System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart**
but its not working.
thanks
i have this code

```
**<a href="javascript:;" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><img src="<?php echo $this->getskinUrl('');?>images/buy.gif" alt=""></a>**
```

who i redirect it to product page

Comment: you need to redirect on product detail page ??

Comment: @GohilRajesh Yes i want the buy now button to redirect to product details pages

Comment: ok many thanks i fixed it :)

Comment: Happy to here u fixed it